# Jython + java запуск python внутри java

Tags: python, java

хочу в одинокого написать какую нибудь игру(стрелялку), и закончить её очень хочу ещё при жизни))
поэтому мне не подходит даже чистый java, потому что слишком медленно будет идти разработка, но есть два нюанса:
 - движок есть нормальный только под java (jmonkeyengine)
 - и почти полностью вся игра должна быть написана на питоне

Сейчас всё запускается образно как java -jar jython.jar start.py
Под нормальными осями запуск конечно проблем не вызовет, Но хочется запустить это ещё и под android-ом, и вот тут встаёт вопрос.

Как подсунуть питон-код в виде папки с кучей файлов в режиме embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. В ОС Android используется реализация JVM под названием "Dalvik". Она очень специфична и, даже, не использует "родной" байт-код Java. Dalvik!=JVM и на этой виртуальной машине нету поддержки большого количества функционала, в том числе Jython.

Как вариант, рекомендую смотреть в сторону [ignifuga](http://ignifuga.org/) или [pygame](http://pygame.renpy.org/)

Comment: так то оно так, но вы говорите не про всё, дело в том что Jython умеет компилировать питон программу в статические class файлы. и тут начинается самое весёлое.  
  
можно попробовать скопировать их в src проекта, также добавить и jython зависимости и попробовать использовать. т.е. jython-у в этом случае ничего компилировать уже не требуется.  
  
что скажете?

Comment: Да, файлы "*.class" можно забросить в src, но боюсь, что от этого ситуация не улучшиться. Насколько Я понимаю, будет существовать зависимость от библиотеки jython. То есть подобным образом необходимо будет интегрировать "jython.jar" и все последующие зависимости.
Но попробовать все-таки стоит, возможно Я ошибаюсь ;)

Comment: не нужно писать игры на питоне с под жавы для андроида. Это не декстоп, здесь ресурсы не бесконечны.

Comment: Есть достаточно [альтернатив][3]
[3]: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/13/game-engines-for-android